# Turn subclass into a dimension in python

Tags: python, arrays, reshape, dimension

I looked through python and pandas libs about pivoting of tables in python, but have not found method how to group subclass within rows into a new dimension. For example I have n columns with features - length, mass , volume, pressure, time etc. And rows representing objects A1,A1,A2,A2,A2,A2,A3,A4,A4,A4,A4. I want to create 4D array in python with dimensions - features, date, and "single" objects(A1,A2,A3,A4). So rows subclasses are regrouped into single objects with additional dimensions.

Thanx!

Comment: Did I answer your request and helped you solve your problem? If yes, do not forget to validate my answer; otherwise, feel free to request more help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function of Pandas.

Usage, taken from the documentation example:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
...     'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
...     'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
...     'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']})

>>> df
    foo   bar  baz  zoo
0   one   A    1    x
1   one   B    2    y
2   one   C    3    z
3   two   A    4    q
4   two   B    5    w
5   two   C    6    t

>>> df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
bar  A   B   C
foo
one  1   2   3
two  4   5   6
```